# Generator of a multiplicative cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Practical method of calculating primitive roots modulo a prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156213/practical-method-of-calculating-primitive-roots-modulo-a-prime)

Given a prime $p$, is there an efficient procedure to find the generator of the multiplicative cyclic group $\{1, 2, ..., p-1\}$?

Comment: You will probably want to read http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156213/practical-method-of-calculating-primitive-roots-modulo-a-prime/

Comment: Discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/124408/11619), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/52545/11619), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/141680/11619), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/164049/11619) and to some extent also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/166866/11619).

Comment: All assuming that the group structure is meant to be the multiplication of residue classes modulo $p$ :-)